# Most lightweight way to create a random string and a random hexadecimal number

Tags: python

What is the most lightweight way to create a random string of 30 characters like the following?

> ufhy3skj5nca0d2dfh9hwd2tbk9sw1

And an hexadecimal number of 30 digits like the followin?

> 8c6f78ac23b4a7b8c0182d7a89e9b1

Comment: How (why?) is it that none of the (well-crafted) answers have been accepted?

Answer (score 143):

I got a faster one for the hex output.  Using the same t1 and t2 as above:

```
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer("''.join(random.choice('0123456789abcdef') for n in xrange(30))", "import random")
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer("binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(15))", "import os, binascii")
>>> t3 = timeit.Timer("'%030x' % random.randrange(16**30)", "import random")
>>> for t in t1, t2, t3:
...     t.timeit()
... 
28.165037870407104
9.0292739868164062
5.2836320400238037
```

`t3` only makes one call to the random module, doesn't have to build or read a list, and then does the rest with string formatting.

Comment: Nice. Just generate a random number 30 hex digits long and print it out. Obvious when pointed out. Nice one.

Comment: Interesting, I kind of forgot that Python (and the random module) handles bigints natively.

Comment: See yaronf's answer below on using `string.hexdigits`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15462293/311288
_"`string.hexdigits` returns `0123456789abcdefABCDEF` (both lowercase and uppercase), [...]. Instead, just use `random.choice('0123456789abcdef')`."_

Comment: Use [`getrandbits`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.getrandbits) instead of `randrange` to make it even faster.

Comment: @robinst has a good point. `'%030x' % random.getrandbits(60)` is even faster than `'%030x' % random.randrange(16**30)`, likely because it doesn't haven't have to do any conversion to/from big-ints

Comment: t3 is nice. to avoid collision use `uuid.uuid1().hex[:30]` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519896/generate-unique-hashes-for-django-models#2520136)

Answer (score 95):

In Py3.6+, another option is to use the new standard `secrets` module:

Random alphanumeric string:

```
In []:
import secrets
n = 30*3//4 # see note
secrets.token_urlsafe(n)

Out[]:
'teRq7IqhaRU0S3euX1ji9f58WzUkrg'
```

Note: `token_urlsafe()` uses base64 encoding which means you need to reduce the requested number by `3//4` to get exactly `30`. Alternatively, split the returned string to the first 30.
It may also include `_-` - unclear if that is acceptable

Random hexadecimal string:

```
In []:
secrets.token_hex(15)

Out[]:
'8d9bad5b43259c6ee27d9aadc7b832'
```

Timings:

```
In []:
%timeit secrets.token_urlsafe(n)

Out[]:
788 ns ± 4.32 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In []:
%timeit secrets.token_hex(15)

Out[]:
631 ns ± 2.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 94):

30 digit hex string:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(15).hex()
"c84766ca4a3ce52c3602bbf02ad1f7"
```

The advantage is that this gets randomness directly from the OS, which might be more secure and/or faster than the random(), and you don't have to seed it.

Comment: that's interesting, and probably a good choice for generating the 30 digit hex number he wants. probably could use urandom and a slice operator to generate the alphanumeric string also.

Comment: I did take a look at the other functions in binascii, they do have base64 and uuencode, but no way to generate the first kind of strings he wants (base36).

Comment: Is this random/unique enough to be used in, say, session tokens?

Comment: A: No. Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817882/unique-session-id-in-python/6092448#6092448

Comment: How does one specify the length?

Comment: Since 3.5 you don't need binascii.  `os.urandom(13).hex()`  works a charm

Answer (score 34):

```
import string
import random
lst = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(30)]
s = "".join(lst)
print s
ocwbKCiuAJLRJgM1bWNV1TPSH0F2Lb
```

Comment: and random.choice(string.hexdigits)

Comment: One might prefer the more cryptographically secure `random.SystemRandom().choice`

Comment: xrange() should be range() - NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: xrange is correct (and usually better) in python 2.x

Comment: Bear in mind that this post was written in 2010 when most people were still using Python 2

Answer (score 28):

Dramatically faster solution than those here:

```
timeit("'%0x' % getrandbits(30 * 4)", "from random import getrandbits")
0.8056681156158447
```

Comment: One user has to try all the methods on the same machine to get an accurate baseline. Hardware specs can make a big difference.  >>>> timeit.timeit("'%0x' % getrandbits(30 * 4)", "from random import getrandbits")
 
0.2471246949999113</pre>

Comment: Thank you, this much faster than the others above. `%timeit '%030x' % randrange(16**30)` gives 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 µs per loop while `%timeit '%0x' % getrandbits(30 * 4)` gives
1000000 loops, best of 3: 396 ns per loop

Answer (score 17):

Note: `random.choice(string.hexdigits)` is incorrect, because `string.hexdigits` returns `0123456789abcdefABCDEF` (both lowercase and uppercase), so you will get a biased result, with the hex digit 'c' twice as likely to appear as the digit '7'. Instead, just use `random.choice('0123456789abcdef')`.

Answer (score 8):

```
In [1]: import random                                    

In [2]: hex(random.getrandbits(16))                      
Out[2]: '0x3b19'
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality, you may want to improve it.

Comment: Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: No idea. I just thought you should know that

Comment: Usually some sort of explanation is nice to have, even if it's obvious. Why is this answer better than the others or what characteristics does it exhibit folks should know about?

Comment: @ggorlen I don't see a way to offer any explanation that could be useful. This is simple and short, not much else

Answer (score 6):

one-line function:

```
import random
import string

def generate_random_key(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(length))

print generate_random_key(30)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another Method :

```
from Crypto import Random
import binascii

my_hex_value = binascii.hexlify(Random.get_random_bytes(30))
```

The point is : **byte value is always equal to the value in hex**.

Answer (score 4):

Incidentally, this is the result of using `timeit` on the two approaches that have been suggested:

Using `random.choice()`:

```
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer("''.join(random.choice(string.hexdigits) for n in xrange(30))", "import random, string")
>>> t1.timeit()
69.558588027954102
```

Using `binascii.b2a_hex()`:

```
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer("binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(15))", "import os, binascii")
>>> t2.timeit()
16.288421154022217
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a faster one compared to what jcdyer has mentioned. This takes ~50% of his fastest  method.

```
from numpy.random.mtrand import RandomState
import binascii
rand = RandomState()

lo = 1000000000000000
hi = 999999999999999999
binascii.b2a_hex(rand.randint(lo, hi, 2).tostring())[:30]

>>> timeit.Timer("binascii.b2a_hex(rand.randint(lo,hi,2).tostring())[:30]", \
...                 'from __main__ import lo,hi,rand,binascii').timeit()
1.648831844329834         <-- this is on python 2.6.6
2.253110885620117         <-- this on python 2.7.5
```

If you want in base64:

```
binascii.b2a_base64(rand.randint(lo, hi, 3).tostring())[:30]
```

You can change the size parameter passed to randint (last arg) to vary the output length based on your requirement. So, for a 60 char one:

```
binascii.b2a_hex(rand.randint(lo, hi, 4).tostring())[:60]
```

Comment: A slight variation:  `binascii.b2a_hex(np.random.rand(np.ceil(N/16)).view(dtype=int))[:N]` where `N=30`.

Comment: @dan-man Thanks for this optional method. However, I find that it's consumes atleast 5x more time. Do you notice that as well?

Answer (score 2):

This is for sure not the most lightweight version, but it is random and it's easy to adjust the alphabet / length you want:

```
import random

def generate(random_chars=12, alphabet="0123456789abcdef"):
    r = random.SystemRandom()
    return ''.join([r.choice(alphabet) for i in range(random_chars)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Compact way of generating a random hex string 32 characters in length, using the `random` module:

```
print(format(random.getrandbits(128), '032x'))
```

Comment: Actually `format(random.getrandbits(128), 'x')` is enough

Answer (score 0):

adding one more answer to the mix that performs faster than @eemz solution and is also fully alphanumeric. Note that this does *not* give you a hexidecimal answer.

```py
import random
import string

LETTERS_AND_DIGITS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def random_choice_algo(width):
  return ''.join(random.choice(LETTERS_AND_DIGITS) for i in range(width))

def random_choices_algo(width):
  return ''.join(random.choices(LETTERS_AND_DIGITS, k=width))


print(generate_random_string(10))
# prints "48uTwINW1D"
```

a quick benchmark yields

```py
from timeit import timeit
from functools import partial

arg_width = 10
print("random_choice_algo", timeit(partial(random_choice_algo, arg_width)))
# random_choice_algo 8.180561417000717
print("random_choices_algo", timeit(partial(random_choices_algo, arg_width)))
# random_choices_algo 3.172438014007639
```

Answer (score 0):

**Random String (letters and numbers):**

```py
import random
import string

def generate_random_string(length=30):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    result = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
    return result

random_string = generate_random_string()
print(random_string)
```

**Random Hexadecimal String:**

```py
import random
import string

def generate_random_hex_string(length=30):
    characters = string.digits + 'abcdef'  # Hexadecimal digits
    result = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
    return result

random_hex_string = generate_random_hex_string()
print(random_hex_string)
```

For basic random string generation, the `random` and `string` modules are very lightweight and efficient because they are part of Python's standard library. This means you don't need to install any external packages. So that will be most lightweight and quickest way.

---

If you need these strings for security-sensitive purposes, like generating passwords or API tokens, consider using the secrets module instead:

```py
import secrets
import string

# Random string of 30 characters
random_string = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(30))

# Hexadecimal number of 30 digits
random_hex = hex(secrets.randbits(120))[2:]  # 120 bits is 30 hexadecimal digits

print(random_string) # 03ulu22q2yxxel4h1a4xwxuf15xemx
print(random_hex) # 539aaca57247132fd08a325a514aea
```