# Why is reversing a list with slicing slower than reverse iterator

Tags: python

There are at least two ways to reverse a list in Python, but the iterator approach is much faster (at least in Python 2.7.x).  I want to understand what contributes to this speed difference.

```
>>> x = range(1000)
>>> %timeit x[::-1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.99 us per loop
>>> %timeit reversed(x)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 169 ns per loop
```

I suspect the speed difference is due to at least the following:

1. `reversed` is written in C
2. `reversed` is an iterator, so less memory overhead

I tried to use the `dis` module to get a better view of these operations, but it wasn't too helpful.  I had to put these operations in a function to disassemble them.

```
>> def reverselist(_list):
...     return _list[::-1]
... 
>>> dis.dis(reverselist)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (_list)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
             12 BUILD_SLICE              3
             15 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def reversed_iter(_list):
...     return reversed(_list)
... 
>>> dis.dis(reversed_iter)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (reversed)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (_list)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

What all exactly happens during a slicing operation, is there a lot of memory overhead?  Maybe slicing is implemented in pure Python?

Comment: As a side note, I didn't have to put these operations into a method in order to use the `dis` module.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270888/why-is-startswith-slower-than-slicing) has a nice little `lambda` than compiles the code string first (required) then passes it to `dis.dis`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because `reversed` returns an [`iterator`](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) while slicing returns a whole list.

```
>>> lis = range(10)
>>> lis[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> reversed(lis)
<listreverseiterator object at 0x909dd0c>
```

You've to use `list()` to convert that iterator into a whole list:

```
>>> lis = range(10**5)
>>> %timeit lis[::-1]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list(reversed(lis))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.13 ms per loop
```

**Help** on `reversed`:

```
>>> reversed?
Type:       type
String Form:<type 'reversed'>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
reversed(sequence) -> reverse iterator over values of the sequence

Return a reverse iterator
```

Comment: Sorry for being off topic, but in which python version does the `?` work for help?

Comment: Well geez that seems obvious, apparently it's too early in the day for  me.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @septi the `?` is in the Ipython shell, not a particular version of Python.

Comment: @septi It's IPython shell.

Answer (score 7):

`reversed()` returns an iterator. It doesn't *actually* reverse anything until you loop over it. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

> Return a reverse *[iterator](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator)*.

You need to compare the time it takes to turn the result of `reversed()` into a list again:

```
%timeit list(reversed(x))
```

Creating just the iterator (which is nothing but a reference to the original list and a item pointer that is initialized to the length of the list) does't take any time at all.

Having to turn `reversed()` back into a list makes it a *lot* slower:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> x = range(1000)
>>> timeit.timeit('x[::-1]', 'from __main__ import x')
4.623600006103516
>>> timeit.timeit('list(reversed(x))', 'from __main__ import x')
16.647125005722046
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed this.  Thanks for the good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`reversed()` doesn't actually reverse anything, it merely returns an object that can be used to iterate over the container's elements in reverse order. This is why it is faster than actually reversing the elements.

Note that you have also `reverse()` that is doing the same as slicing operator.

`reverse()` operates in place. slicing operator returns a list object.

Comment: `list.reverse()` operates in-place not `reversed`.