# Python Sorting Lists based on Values inside the List (from right to left)

Tags: python

With Python, how to sort the lists based on the values in the list (from right to left)?

For example:

```
[2005, 6, 21], [2003, 5, 21], [2005, 5, 11], [2003, 5, 22]
```

should return

```
[2003, 5, 21], [2003, 5, 22], [2005, 5, 11], [2005, 6, 21]
```

Comment: `sorted([[2005, 6, 21], [2003, 5, 21], [2005, 5, 11], [2003, 5, 22]])` ?

Comment: `sorted(a)` or `a.sort()` both will do, as the default sorting order is left to right

Comment: `l = [[2005, 6, 21], [2003, 5, 21], [2005, 5, 11], [2003, 5, 22]]` `l.sort()`

Comment: Did no-one else notice the "right to left" bit in the question? It seems to be inconsitent with the expected result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sorting a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608210/sorting-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected result, that's *not* right-to-left sorting. In that case, the default sort works just fine:

```py
>>> xyzzy = [[2005, 6, 21], [2003, 5, 21], [2005, 5, 11], [2003, 5, 22]]
>>> sorted(xyzzy)
[[2003, 5, 21], [2003, 5, 22], [2005, 5, 11], [2005, 6, 21]]
```

If you *did* want to sort based on right-to-left order in each sub-list, you can provide a `key` function/callable which does the work for you. Since you want the same comparison but in reverse, just use the reversed list for the comparison:

```py
>>> sorted(xyzzy, key=lambda x: x[::-1])
[[2005, 5, 11], [2003, 5, 21], [2005, 6, 21], [2003, 5, 22]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the sorted() in python.

```
input_list = [2005, 6, 21], [2003, 5, 21], [2005, 5, 11], [2003, 5, 22]
sorted_list = sorted(input_list)
```

Declaring the `input_list` like above will create a tuple of lists and `input_list.sort()` will not work as sort does not support tuple. If you need to use sort(), you have to first convert the tuple of lists to list of lists and then perform sort operation like below.

```
input_list = [[2005, 6, 21], [2003, 5, 21], [2005, 5, 11], [2003, 5, 22]]
input_list.sort()
```

If you need to sort from left to right, you can use the reverse parameter.

```
sorted_list = sorted(input_list, reverse=True)
```

or

```
input_list.sort(reverse=True)
```

Note that `sorted()` will return the sorted list, whereas `sort()` will replace the input list with the sorted list.