# python pandas: why map is faster?

Tags: python, pandas

in pandas' manual, there is this example about indexing:

```
In [653]: criterion = df2['a'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('t'))
In [654]: df2[criterion]
```

then Wes wrote:

```
**# equivalent but slower**
In [655]: df2[[x.startswith('t') for x in df2['a']]]
```

can anyone here explain a bit why the map approach is faster? Is this a python feature or this is a pandas feature?

Comment: I bet you `from operator import methodcaller\\df2['a'].map(methodcaller("startswith", "t"))` will be significantly faster yet.

Comment: @TimPietzcker; it's not using the built-in `map` (which would be slower in this case).

Comment: @Veedrac: I see; I was just wondering where the second parameter to `map` was :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Arguments about why a certain way of doing things in Python "should be" faster can't be taken too seriously, because you're often measuring implementation details which may behave differently in certain situations.  As a result, when people guess what should be faster, they're often (usually?) wrong.  For example, I find that `map` can actually be slower.  Using this setup code:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import random, string

def make_test(num, width):
    s = [''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, width)) for i in range(num)]
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a": s})
    return df
```

Let's compare the time they take to make the indexing object -- whether a `Series` or a `list` -- and the resulting time it takes to use that object to index into the `DataFrame`.  It could be, for example, that making a list is fast but before using it as an index it needs to be internally converted to a `Series` or an `ndarray` or something and so there's extra time added there.

First, for a small frame:

```
>>> df = make_test(10, 10)
>>> %timeit df['a'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('t'))
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.8 µs per loop
>>> %timeit [x.startswith('t') for x in df['a']]
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.6 µs per loop
>>> %timeit df['a'].str.startswith("t")
10000 loops, best of 3: 118 µs per loop
>>> %timeit df[df['a'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('t'))]
1000 loops, best of 3: 304 µs per loop
>>> %timeit df[[x.startswith('t') for x in df['a']]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 194 µs per loop
>>> %timeit df[df['a'].str.startswith("t")]
1000 loops, best of 3: 348 µs per loop
```

and in this case the listcomp is fastest. That doesn't actually surprise me too much, to be honest, because going via a `lambda` is likely to be slower than using `str.startswith` directly, but it's really hard to guess.  10 is small enough we're probably still measuring things like setup costs for `Series`; what happens in a larger frame?

```
>>> df = make_test(10**5, 10)
>>> %timeit df['a'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('t'))
10 loops, best of 3: 46.6 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [x.startswith('t') for x in df['a']]
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit df['a'].str.startswith("t")
10 loops, best of 3: 48.5 ms per loop
>>> %timeit df[df['a'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('t'))]
10 loops, best of 3: 47.1 ms per loop
>>> %timeit df[[x.startswith('t') for x in df['a']]]
10 loops, best of 3: 52.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit df[df['a'].str.startswith("t")]
10 loops, best of 3: 49.6 ms per loop
```

And now it seems like the `map` is winning when used as an index, although the difference is marginal.  But not so fast: what if we manually turn the listcomp into an `array` or a `Series`?

```
>>> %timeit df[np.array([x.startswith('t') for x in df['a']])]
10 loops, best of 3: 40.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit df[pd.Series([x.startswith('t') for x in df['a']])]
10 loops, best of 3: 37.5 ms per loop
```

and now the listcomp wins again!

Conclusion: who knows?  But never believe anything without `timeit` results, and even then you have to ask whether you're testing what you think you are.

Comment: can you submit this as a PR for docs : https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3871, trying to create a new section

Comment: This is probably also the section of the docs where Wes states that [startswith is slower than slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270888/why-is-startswith-slower-than-slicing)!