# Why is string's startswith slower than in?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython, python-internals, startswith

Surprisingly, I find `startswith` is slower than `in`:

```
In [10]: s="ABCD"*10

In [11]: %timeit s.startswith("XYZ")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 307 ns per loop

In [12]: %timeit "XYZ" in s
10000000 loops, best of 3: 81.7 ns per loop
```

As we all know, the `in` operation needs to search the whole string and `startswith` just needs to check the first few characters, so `startswith` should be more efficient.

When `s` is big enough, `startswith` is faster:

```
In [13]: s="ABCD"*200

In [14]: %timeit s.startswith("XYZ")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 306 ns per loop

In [15]: %timeit "XYZ" in s
1000000 loops, best of 3: 666 ns per loop
```

So it seems that calling `startswith` has some overhead which makes it slower when the string is small.

And than I tried to figure out what's the overhead of the `startswith` call.

First, I used an `f` variable to reduce the cost of the dot operation - as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13271125/552942) - here we can see `startswith` is still slower:

```
In [16]: f=s.startswith

In [17]: %timeit f("XYZ")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 270 ns per loop
```

Further, I tested the cost of an empty function call:

```
In [18]: def func(a): pass

In [19]: %timeit func("XYZ")
10000000 loops, best of 3: 106 ns per loop
```

Regardless of the cost of the dot operation and function call, the time of `startswith` is about (270-106)=164ns, but the `in` operation takes only 81.7ns. It seems there are still some overheads for `startswith`, what's that?

Add the test result between `startswith` and `__contains__` as suggested by poke and lvc:

```
In [28]: %timeit s.startswith("XYZ")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 314 ns per loop

In [29]: %timeit s.__contains__("XYZ")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 192 ns per loop
```

Comment: To get a more similar result, you can do `s.__contains__("XYZ")` as this will take the same route as `s.startswith("XYZ")` then (using the `in` operator will short-cut the member access). However, `startswith` is still slower for me then.

Comment: I think the remainder of the performance difference is due to `__contains__` being fully typed *in C*, while `startswith` does actual argument parsing and stuff (you can also pass a tuple).

Comment: What version of Python are you using? On 3.4.3, I get `s.startswith("XYZ")` report 153ns, and `s.__contains__("XYZ")` reports 169ns. As @poke says, using `in` will use completely different lookup rules than the method call - it can be looked up directly from a function pointer at the C level, while the method lookup does two dictionary searches and *then* has to do a Python-level function call. Timing those things separately can give you *some* idea of the difference, but isn't necessarily exact. On your numbers,  subtracting both those overheads makes the time for `startswith` *negative*!

Comment: I went even further and checked `%timeit "XYZ" == s[0:3]` which gives me `10000000 loops, best of 3: 94 ns per loop` while `%timeit "XYZ" in s`
`10000000 loops, best of 3: 59.2 ns per loop`. Tested with python 3.4.3.

(it seems that in my case, slicing gives "some" overhead, as `%timeit "XYZ" in s[0:3]` results in `10000000 loops, best of 3: 101 ns per loop`)

Comment: @lvc I'm using CPython 2.7.5. I did a test between `startswith` and `__contains__` as poke and you suggested, `startswith` is still slower, the same the result as poke said.

Comment: Actually `in` doesn't need to search the whole string if it finds the argument early on. I'd expect these two calls to perform basically the same here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit While that’s true, `s` is a repetition of the string `"ABCD"`, so the whole string has to be searched in order to come to the conclusion that `"XYZ"` is not contained within.

Comment: @poke: Er, good point :D

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, if you use `s.__contains__("XYZ")` you get a result that is more similar to `s.startswith("XYZ")` because it needs to take the same route: Member lookup on the string object, followed by a function call. This is usually somewhat expensive (not enough that you should worry about of course). On the other hand, when you do `"XYZ" in s`, the parser interprets the operator and can short-cut the member access to the `__contains__` (or rather the implementation behind it, because `__contains__` itself is just one way to access the implementation).

You can get an idea about this by looking at the bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis('"XYZ" in s')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('XYZ')
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('s.__contains__("XYZ")')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__contains__)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 ('XYZ')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

So comparing `s.__contains__("XYZ")` with `s.startswith("XYZ")` will produce a more similar result, however for your example string `s`, the `startswith` will still be slower.

To get to that, you could check the implementation of both. Interesting to see for the [contains implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e39c4373b83f/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l10889) is that it is statically typed, and just assumes that the argument is a unicode object itself. So this is quite efficient.

The [`startswith` implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e39c4373b83f/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l13124) however is a “dynamic” Python method which requires the implementation to actually parse the arguments. `startswith` also supports a tuple as an argument, which makes the whole start-up of the method a bit slower: (shortened by me, with my comments):

```c
static PyObject * unicode_startswith(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    // argument parsing
    PyObject *subobj;
    PyObject *substring;
    Py_ssize_t start = 0;
    Py_ssize_t end = PY_SSIZE_T_MAX;
    int result;
    if (!stringlib_parse_args_finds("startswith", args, &subobj, &start, &end))
        return NULL;

    // tuple handling
    if (PyTuple_Check(subobj)) {}

    // unicode conversion
    substring = PyUnicode_FromObject(subobj);
    if (substring == NULL) {}

    // actual implementation
    result = tailmatch(self, substring, start, end, -1);
    Py_DECREF(substring);
    if (result == -1)
        return NULL;
    return PyBool_FromLong(result);
}
```

This is likely a big reason why `startswith` is slower for strings for which a `contains` is fast because of its simplicity.

Comment: the links for the implementations are broken

Comment: @mounaim Apparently, Python’s Mercurial server just went down for a few seconds. It’s working again now.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because `str.startswith()` does more than `str.__contains__()`, and also because I believe `str.__contains__` operates fully in C, whereas `str.startswith()` has to interact with Python types. Its signature is `str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])`, where prefix can be a tuple of strings to try.

Comment: "Does more" is vague and probably not true. Finding a substring efficiently is not a trivial problem. [List of algorithms.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Single_pattern_algorithms). In contrast, finding a prefix is quite easy and in general faster.

Comment: You're right @PaulDraper; I was up late when I wrote that :P. And thanks for the edit @LightnessRacesinOrbit :).