# superfast regexmatch in large text file

Tags: python

I want this code to work fast.

```
import re
with open('largetextfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pattern = re.compile("^1234567")
        if pattern.match(line):
            print (line)
```

takes 19 seconds.

I modified it:

```
import re
with open('largetextfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "1234567" in line:
            pattern = re.compile("^1234567")
            if pattern.match(line):
                print (line)
```

takes 7 seconds.

So the question is, is there any better way?

I got two ideas from community and based on that I asked the detailed question at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135159/python-search-for-array-in-large-text-file

Comment: Small thing to change is to take the pattern definition out of the loop

Comment: hmm. Let me check.

Comment: got one second benefit.

Comment: Maybe instead of checking `if "1234567" in line:` chech if the first 7 characters in line are equal to "1234567" as a string (no `in`).

Comment: shouldn't this be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You are compiling the pattern on each iteration. Take it out of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if this matches your requirement:

```
with open('largetextfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('1234567'):
            print line
```

Comment: @scripting.filesystemobject can you check time on this answer.  I'm guessing it is much faster than yours

Comment: Almost half than my code. I will validate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're matching a string you don't need regular expressions, so you can use this

```
with open('bigfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:     
        if line[:7]=="1234567": 
            print (line)
```

I noticed that using string slicing is slightly faster than `startswith` and found out this has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13270888/2314737)

Comment: Thanks. It is faster.

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform tests, I copied in a file **AAA.txt** the following text of 6,31 MB and around 128.000 lines:
http://norvig.com/big.txt
Then with the help of random module, I changed it to a file **BBB.txt** by randomly inserting `'1234567'` at the starts of 1000 lines of it.

I tested several solutions on this modified text.

I can't discriminate which one of the following ones is the fastest, but I think they're all faster than other solutions that I read in this page and other solutions of mine.

They are based on the fact that the "in"-test `'string' in 'anotherstring'` is tremendously fast.

```
def in_and_startswith(x):
    return '1234567' in x and x.startswith('1234567')
with open('BBB.txt') as f:
    for line in filter(in_and_startswith, f):
        x=0
```

.

```
def in_and_find(x):
    return '1234567' in x and x.find('1234567')==0
with open('BBB.txt') as f:
    for line in filter(in_and_find, f):
        x=0
```

.

```
def just_in(x):
    return '1234567' in x

with open('BBB.txt') as f:
    for line in filter(just_in, f):
        if line.startswith('1234567'):
            x=0

with open('BBB.txt') as f:
    for line in filter(just_in, f):
        if line.find('1234567')==0:
            x=0
```

Note that I tested with just the instruction `x=0` that has no particular sense, to avoid instruction `print(line)` because `print()` is an instruction that takes a long time to execute. 
So repeating several `print()` instructions is much longer than printing just one string obtained as joining all the strings that must be printed.

Test the execution times of

```
for x in ['hkjh','kjhoi','3135487j','kjhskdkfh','54545779']:
    print(x)
```

and

```
print('\n'.join(x for x i['hkjh','kjhoi','313587j','kjhskdkfh','54545779']))
```

you'll see the difference

Comment: Thanks for huge help.

Comment: It will take some time for me to understand.