# how to extract all the href from the a tags and test if they start with '/' or not using beautifulsoup? - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to extract all the hrefers from the a tags, but some of the hrefers starts like "/videos.com" instead "www.example/videos.com", they haven't the domain. So what I'm trying to do is extracting all the hrefers from the a tags but I want to test if it starts with "/", if so I will add the domain "www.example.com".

I wanted something like:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    domain_name = 'www.example.com'

    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        if a['href'] starts with '/':
            link = domain_name + a['href']
        else:
            link = a['href']
```

How to extract all the hrefs from the a tags and test if they start with '/' or not?

I was thinking to use regex, but I'm not sure how to say "if a['href'] starts with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for **[`.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

domain_name = 'www.example.com'

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if a['href'].startswith('/'):
        link = domain_name + a['href']
    else:
        link = a['href']
```

But note you can also operate with slicings:

```
if a['href'][0] == '/':
```

Some performance analysis can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13271125/5103802).

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. The second approach operating with slicings seems to be even better and faster.