# Check if there is at least one element starting with specific character in a list

Tags: python, startswith

I have a list containing a group of numbers (`str`) , and I want to check if there is at least one element in the list starting with `'+'` .

The problem with my code is that an infinite loop will occur if no number starts with `'+'`, I need a better solution?

```
my_list = ['11112352', '222222003', '5682052003', '21543003', '98756003', '+004454883']
while True:
    for number in my_list:
        if number.startswith('+'):
            break
```

Comment: Avoid using `while` loops for such problems and stick with just for loops if possible since all you are doing is iterating through each element of the list

Comment: Hi!Welcome to SO! Could you please indicate why you need the `while` loop? Your problem requires iterating through each element of the list and break if a string starts with +. Hence the while loop is not necessary.

Comment: Hey, thanks, My problem is to check that there is at least one element starting with '+'  in the list , I am asking for a better solution

Comment: [Using `startswith` for a single character is inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13270888/13552470). As in my answer, simply use a slice of `[0]`.

Comment: we can use startswith for one or multiple characters , it's a more generic solution that we can apply for different cases , that's why I accepted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if any element starts with a `'+'`, use builtin functions [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith). You can nearly write down the exact words as Python code:

```
starts_with_plus = any(element.startswith('+') for element in my_list)
```

This will return a boolean value. This will also return on the first instance where the condition is `True`, like returning out of a loop, making this very efficient.

If you want to check for other prefixes as well, just put it in a small function:

```
def starts_with(lst, prefix):
    return any(element.startswith(prefix) for element in lst)

starts_with_plus = starts_with(my_list, '+')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = ['11112352', '222222003', '5682052003', '21543003', '98756003', '+004454883']
for number in my_list:
    if number.startswith('+'):
        break
```

This:

```
while True:
```

is unnecessary, the for loop will already check every item in the list

To make it clearer, if it print every iteration:

```
my_list = ['11112352', '222222003', '5682052003', '21543003', '98756003', '+004454883']
for number in my_list:
    print(number)
    if number.startswith('+'):
        break
```

I get

```
11112352
222222003
5682052003
21543003
98756003
+004454883
```

so as you can see the while loop is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler solution:

```
my_list = ['11112352', '222222003', '5682052003', '21543003', '98756003', '+004454883']
result = [x for x in my_list if x.startswith('+')]
if result:
    # do something if result is not empty
else:
    # result is empty -- no '+' entries in my_list
```

Comment: An issue with this is, for example, if the list is really really long, and say the first element starts with a `+`, you would still be checking every element in the list unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a `True`/`False` result, you can try this:

```
any(number for number in my_list if number[0] == "+")
```

Function any delivers `True` if at least one element of the list passed as argument is `True`.

Edited as suggested by [Ann Zen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13552470/ann-zen). See also [How exactly any works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505456/how-exactly-does-the-python-any-function-work)

Comment: This is inefficient as it will need to process *all* the strings before returning `True`/`False`. Please refer to my answer for the proper way of using `any`.

Comment: The enclosing `[ ]` are actually counter-productive here since they'll force the whole list to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) method:

```
my_list = ['11112352', '222222003', '5682052003', '21543003', '98756003', '+004454883']
print(any(s[0] == '+' for s in my_list))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of a `for` loop and a `flag` variable:

```
flag = 0

for item in my_list:
    if item.startswith('+'):
        flag = 1
        break

print(flag)
```

If you get an output of `0`, then it's obvious that no element starts with a `+`. On the other hand, if the output of the print statement is `1`, there's at least one element that starts with a `+`.