# Generate random strings in pandas

Tags: pandas

I would like to create a string of one million keys with 200 different values:

```
N = 1000000 
uniques_keys = [pd.core.common.rands(3) for i in range(200)] 
keys = [random.choice(uniques_keys) for i in range(N)]
```

However, I get the following error

```
In [250]:import pandas as pd 

In [251]:pd.core.common.rands(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-251-31d12e0a07e7>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.core.common.rands(3)

AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.common' has no attribute 'rands'
```

I use pandas version 0.18.0.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Create a string of one million keys with 200 different values:                       N = 1000000 
uniques_keys = [pd.core.common.rands(3) for i in range(200)] 
keys = [random.choice(uniques_keys) for i in range(N)]

Answer (score 16):

You can use:

```
In [14]: pd.util.testing.rands_array?
Signature: pd.util.testing.rands_array(nchars, size, dtype='O')
Docstring: Generate an array of byte strings.
```

---

Demo:

```
In [15]: N = 1000000

In [16]: s_arr = pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, N)

In [17]: s_arr
Out[17]: array(['L6d2GwhHdT', '5oki5T8VYm', 'XKUblAUFyL', ..., 'BE5AdCa62a', 'X3zDFKj6iy', 'iwASB9xZV3'], dtype=object)

In [18]: len(s_arr)
Out[18]: 1000000
```

---

**UPDATE:**  from 2020-04-21

In newer Pandas versions you might see the following deprecation warning:

> FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in
>   the public API at pandas.testing instead.

in this case import this function as follows:

```
from pandas._testing import rands_array
```

Comment: Neither `pd.util.testing.rands_array` nor `pd.testing.rands_array` seem to exist in Pandas 1.0.

Comment: @Acumenus it's `._testing`, not `.testing`.

Answer (score 4):

There are several solutions:

**First solution:**

The function `rands` appears to be in `pandas.util.testing` now:

```
pd.util.testing.rands(3)
```

**Second solution:**

Go straight for the underlying `numpy` implementation (as found [in the pandas source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/util/testing.py#L225)):

```
import string
RANDS_CHARS = np.array(list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits),
                       dtype=(np.str_, 1))

nchars = 3
''.join(np.random.choice(RANDS_CHARS, nchars))
```

**Third solution:**

Call [`numpy.random.bytes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.bytes.html) (check that it fulfils your requirements).

**Fourth solution:**

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782229/most-lightweight-way-to-create-a-random-string-and-a-random-hexadecimal-number) for other suggestions.